# In TypeORM how to handle inaccesible cache?

Tags: redis, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

In app.module.ts I have configured TypeORM:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
            type: 'mysql',
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            port: 3306,
            username: process.env.DB_USER,
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.DB_NAME,
            autoLoadEntities: true,
            synchronize: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development',
            cache: {
                alwaysEnabled: false,
                type: 'redis',
                options: {
                    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
                    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
                },
            },
        }),
```

and in repository I have method:

```
async read(id: string): Promise<SomeEntity> | undefined {
        return await this.roomRepository.findOne({
            where: {
                id: id
            },
            cache: {
                id: `entity_${id}`,
                milliseconds: 86400000, //1day
            },
        });
    }
```

This works well, but when redis is down, no select is performed and application hangs up on this method. How to achieve that if redis is unavailable, a select from the database is performed?

Need I get rid of typeORM caching, and implement caching with redis by self?